# Are licensing questions wanted?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Are general licensing questions wanted / allowed on Graphicdesign.SE?

I don't mean specific copyright or legal issues which vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, but broad generic questions like:

- How do graphic designers nowadays deal with the question of signing away usage rights to the client? What is the norm?
- I used a stock image from a royalty-free web site. Now somebody claims to be the author of the image. What do I do?
- How can I protect against third-party claims when using free stock images?
- What do I have to be aware of when buying a font for a client? What can I generally do or not do with the font? (The answer to this one is "read the license agreement", but I still think it would be a good question to have.)

I think these would be great things to talk about - always with the "I am not a lawyer" disclaimer at hand, of course - and it would be very interesting to hear how such issues are dealt with in the industry.

If there's related discussion already that I overlooked while searching, I apologize. In that case, please point me there.

Answer (score 6):

I think these are very valid points, and should be considered. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: +1 Valid and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Over at Stack Overflow, we have the Programmers SE where we can redirect questions like these. Before the Programmers SE, we used to have such questions on SO, if sometimes as community wikis.

So, as we don't (and probably never will) have a Graphic Designers SE, I say these questions are valid here. They should be properly tagged (e.g. legal) though, and some of them might have to be CW.

Comment: That's a good comparison, haven't thought of it that way.

Comment: Not _all_ software licencing questions are welcome on P.SE. Every question that requires legal expertise is off topic. (P.SE mod here)