# what about "Business related questions"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Example:

> I want to sell my graphics on t-shirts, and I have some questions to the experts because I  never did anything similar before:
>   1) Which material of t-shirt I should sell that has good quality?
>   2) What would be a good quantity should I start to produce to test the market (for S, M, X and XL for man)?
>   3) What would be an acceptable cost price for mailing the t-shirt?

or another example:

> I decided to be a freelancer, and I found a company that wants to buy my service, but I have no idea on what to insert on the contract (delivery, payments, what the clients has to do, decisional responsibility, extra costs [like calls, going to the clients, etc..] etc...), anyone has good examples or link to resources where I can start to put together one for myself?

Can be asked? or are we gonna be more technical kind of community?

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the first example is  **off-topic**.

One could ask "Which t-shirt material is best for [type of print]?"; and also questions related to the preparation of the graphic for print should be considered **on-topic**.

Second example's scope is partially being defined in [Are licensing questions wanted?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/are-licensing-questions-wanted) question. Overall I think biz questions are considered **on-topic** if and only if they are:

- obviously designer-related
- not too localized

Startup questions probably should go to [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/).

Comment: "Too localized" is tricky.  A qn that is localised to a design hub city like New York or Amsterdam should be OK, I think.